# mysql difference between "<>" and "is not"

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm currently using mysql 5.7.39 and wondering if someone here could help with the difference between "<>" and "is not"

we have both tests:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a
left join b
on a.column = b.column and b.anothercolumn is not null
```

and this

```
select a.*, b.*
from a
left join b
on a.column = b.column and b.anothercolumn <> null
```

the "anothercolumn" has int(11) values, but will only show data on the first query when using **is not** , while the output from table b will be all empty when using the second query.

I tried to find online what the difference is between **<>** and **is not** but could not  get to a direct answer.

Anyone who knows the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is `NULL` is never equal to itself. It's also never **not** equal to itself. That is, `NULL = NULL` is false, and `NULL <> NULL` is also false.

See this:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/LD9TWaOX

People sometimes see `NULL` as meaning an "empty" or "missing" value, but what it really means in SQL is "unknown". And when you compare something against unknown, *the result is also unknown*. If you then further coerce the unknown result to a boolean, the answer is **always falsy**.

This means the `b.anothercolumn <> null` expression can **never** be true, and this is by design. That is why you must use `IS NOT NULL`.